# is there any function to store logs & send mail to admin?

Tags: errors

I remember that i always used custom codes to log errors in hardcoded path, then send mail to admin (with extra codes), like:

```
if($error_condition){
    file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/xyz.txt',   $message);
    wp_mail(to, subject, content, headers etc...);
}
```

does there exist any native simpler function, like:

```
if($error_condition){
    log_error($message);
}
```

which could send that message to admin and save into log somewhere..